# Placing output files in a different folder breaks viewer and forward search

Tags: texniccenter, forward-inverse-search, sumatrapdf

I am using Miktex 2.9, TexnicCenter 2.02 and Sumatra pdf v3.0 on Windows 10. I would like to place the output files in a different folder so in TexnicCenter I pass the following to the compiler:

```
--output-directory=C:\mypath\pdfs --aux-directory=C:\mypath\aux
```

This works fine and generates the pdf and auxiliary files in the right locations, but now Sumatra cannot locate the output pdf to automatically open after building or do forward search. In TexnicCenter, I have the following set up:

View project's output -> command line

```
"%bm.pdf"
```

Forward search -> DDE command

```
[ForwardSearch("%bm.pdf","%Wc",%l,0,0,1)]
```

How can I modify the above commands to help Sumatra locate the pdf under the new folder?

Comment: I never use `--output-directory` and similar as configuring all tools to do the right thing is really hard with it. And I never use an absolute path like `C:\mypath\aux`.

Comment: Can you suggest a better way of generating pdfs in a separate folder and still have viewer and forward search working properly?

Comment: As I wrote: I don't do this, my files are always in one folder.

Answer (score 1):

after many try and errors I think I found a solution to this question.
With the help of the [TeXnicCenter Configuration](http://texniccenter.sourceforge.net/configuration.html#viewer-tab), the little arrow to the right at the Command line of the *Forward Search* and the option "Main file with further options" *(translated from German Menu)* I found following examples for the `%` parameters:

- Path: **%pm** (Example: *C:\LaTeX Dokumente\Promotion\Promotion.tex*)
- Path without Extension: **%bm** (Example: *C:\LaTeX Dokumente\Promotion\Promotion*)
- Relative Path: **%wm** (Example: *Promotion\Promotion.tex*)
- Directory: **%dm** (Example: *C:\LaTeX Dokumente\Promotion*)
- Name: **%nm** (Example: *Promotion.tex*)
- Name (without) /Title: **%tm** (Example: *Promotion*)
- Extension: **%em** (Example: *tex*)
- Drive: **%rm** (Example: *C:*)

---

I therefore concluded, that the standard `[ForwardSearch("%bm.pdf","%Wc",%l,0,0,1)]` uses just the parameter *"Path without Extension"* and adds the `.pdf` extension.

I'm redirecting the compiler output with the arguments `--aux-directory=.latexaux` and `--output-directory=_LaTeX_PDFs` into two folders in the current working directory. ([*relative vs. absolut paths*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths))

So I tried `[ForwardSearch("%dm\_LaTeX_PDFs\%tm.pdf","%Wc",%l,0,0,1)]` for the viewers *Forward Search* and it works as intended.

---

### To answer your question:

You should try `[ForwardSearch("C:\mypath\aux\%tm.pdf","%Wc",%l,0,0,1)]` as the DDE command of the *Forward Search* option and it should work fine.

---

*I also think it could be helpfull to copy the quote `"` part into the 'View project's output' command line, but it also worked for me without doing it...*

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!